# Decrease the bottom margin in bootstrap header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code for header/footer in my site. IT remains fixed. Here problem is bith bottom margin.

I want to push bottom line i header little up.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/AA3FJ/)

Button adding `bottom-margin` does not solve it?
Can anyone give some clue?

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="email-input navbar-left">
            <div id="input-group-email" class="input-group">
                <input id= "email-input-box" type="email" class="form-control" name = "email" placeholder="xyz@example.com" autocomplete="on" autofocus="autofocus" required="required">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="submit-email-btn" class="btn btn-default" type="button" disabled>Get Notified!</button>
                </span>
            </div>

        <div id="notified-alert" style="display:none; font-size: 18px;font-family: 'calibri'; color: grey; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: -50%;">We stand notified ... :)</div>
        </div>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
<span class="arrorPos">Login <i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the navbar-text class, here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AA3FJ/2/

```
.navbar-text {
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

I think this is what you wanted to do at least, a bit hard to understand your question.

**Edit**: Ok, what you want to do is add a div with .container class around your floated elements in the nav menu

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="email-input navbar-left">
            <div id="input-group-email" class="input-group">
                <input id= "email-input-box" type="email" class="form-control" name = "email" placeholder="xyz@example.com" autocomplete="on" autofocus="autofocus" required="required">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="submit-email-btn" class="btn btn-default" type="button" disabled>Get Notified!</button>
                </span>
            </div>

        <div id="notified-alert" style="display:none; font-size: 18px;font-family: 'calibri'; color: grey; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: -50%;">We stand notified ... :)</div>
        </div>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
<span class="arrorPos">Login <i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i>
        </p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Joseph: thannks, but still alighment issue. Please see here. I want equal up+bottom margin for notification box and login icons. http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/AA3FJ/3/  please expand the window to see correct preview of output

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure i understand your question properly. Try `style="margin-bottom:5px;"` An easy way to set notification box is give constant width.`<input id= "email-input-box" style="width:200px;">`